# Why my page width doesn't fit all resolution

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I have 2 monitors one of them 1920x1080 and the other is 1440x900 resolution. I am doing a website but the website is doesn't fit on 1440x900 why it is happening? I am using % on widths so I think it has to fit but it doesn't. What am I missing can you help me?

**1920x1080 Screenshot** [image: fits properly]

**1440x900 Screenshot** [image: doesnt fit properly]

I am using CSS grid to organize header,slidershow,footer etc. but I am using flexbox inside header,slidershow etc.

**A little part of CSS**

```
body{
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 60px repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
display: flex;
background-color: #009eb3;
}

.inner_header {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
position: relative;
justify-content: space-between;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: 3%;
}
```

EDIT: Here is jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tcwaypq4/4/) i didn't know about this site sorry for it. And I changed my body display to flex.

Comment: This code isn't enough, can you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I added (https://jsfiddle.net/tcwaypq4/4/) sorry i didnt know about jsfiddle i am new to html css

Comment: Is horizontal-scroll an issue for you? refer the following ans, add the property suggested and the scroll will go away.

Comment: Suggestion:  To cover wide range of devices and screens with different resolution, try using bootstrap. It has classes which will help you write code faster and efficient. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should make some changes to your elements, so that they don't go out the page.

```
.informative-menu {
    width: 100%;
}
.info-boxes {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 33.3%;
}
.icon-desc-spans {
    width: 100%;
}
.icon-desc-spans {
    width: 100%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Then, you have to make your bottom-images responsive (e.g.: `width: 50%;`).

Answer (score 0):

```
.informative-menu {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background: green;
}
```

Add  `justify-content: space-evenly;` property in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is

```
margin-left: 3%;
margin-right: 3%;
```

I believe you meant padding there, not margin.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `head` section code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

This should solve it.
You can read allot more about viewport meta tag on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This always helps me.